# Java Enter Event Does Not Activate Handler

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlabel, actionlistener

I am new to Java events, listeners and handlers. I can write code to create a button click event and a working result. However, I cannot get a simple enter event within a TextField to work.

Notice I do declare and call action listeners, input handlers, and define a resulting method execution. (I import java.awt and javax.swing libraries not shown below.)

```
public convertStringToCapitalLetters() {
    setTitle("Convert String to All Capital Letters");
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    inputLabel = new JLabel("Enter String: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    stringTextField = new JTextField(50);
    outputLabel = new JLabel("Capitalized String: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    newStringLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    c.add(inputLabel);
    c.add(stringTextField);
    c.add(outputLabel);
    c.add(newStringLabel);

    inputHandler = new InputHandler();

    stringTextField.addActionListener(inputHandler);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class InputHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str, newStr;

        str = stringTextField.getText();
        newStr = str.toUpperCase();

        newStringLabel.setText(String.format("", newStr));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    convertStringToCapitalLetters capitalConv = new convertStringToCapitalLetters();
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in greater detail. Just what exactly are you trying to do that you're unable to do? What part of your code attempts to do this? Assume that we have no prior knowledge of your problem or your code, and in particular of code not shown.

Comment: You're lucky folks were able to understand your code, but next time, please tell us more. I'm not sure why you never replied to my comment above though.

Comment: Sorry, I'll format my code better next time. I had problems with the code formatting in the text box. My fault though. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just made a very small mistake which is to forget to specify the placeholder `%s` in `String.format()`

Try this:

```
newStringLabel.setText(String.format("%s", newStr));
```

Comment: Wow, you are right. Man, that didn't show up as an error in Eclipse. Thanks for paying attention to details. I'll make sure I do so before I post another question next time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `String.format("", newStr)` call when setting the label's text, you can simply use

```
newStringLabel.setText(newStr);
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks that explains everything. I'll hone in my Eclipse environment's error display and lessen my dumb mistakes.